# Python: Read File and append a lot of list of 28 lines

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

Read a file that contains 10.000 digits. Digits are used 28 lines each so I want to read the file and to store lists of 28 elements.

```
with open(ima) as file:
    for linea in file:
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(ima) as file:
    file_list = f.readlines() # You will have a list with size/28=the number of digits
    # Divide file_list by size 28
```

Comment: Thanks!! But how can I read 28 lines by 28 lines? And have a list of 10000 list of 28 in the end.

Answer (score 0):

From the itertools documentation,

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Which you can call as

```
with open(ima) as inf:
    for group in grouper(inf, 28, ""):
        # now group contains 28 lines from inf
```

Comment: Thanks, it was!! But I'm doing a job and I can't use an external library like itertools..

Comment: "External library"? It's part of the language, included in every installation of Python.